# SHOPP Custom Post Type, conditional tags

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-shopp

I really want to find out what the Custom Post Type is for the SHOPP plugin - is there any way you can fish it out from WP in the code or in the admin? May come in useful to customise other plugins and such.

This is specifically for SHOPP plugin right now, so if anyone knows what it is (or if it has one?!) that would be helpful.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your database, it'll be in the posts table under the `post_type` column for each product.

Or alternately- search the plugin files for calls to `register_post_type`.

Or depending on how the plugin works on the admin side, the URL of the edit screen may tell you: `edit.php?post_type=some_post_type`

Comment: Yep, it's named shopp_product. Also, Shopp just started using custom post types in the 1.2 beta which still is a bit rough around the edges.  For example, currently it does not seem possible (at least in the traditional sense), to add custom meta boxes or even things like custom fields to the shopp_product CPT. This issue is logged in their bug tracker.

Comment: Im not sure that the version i am using; 1.1.9 actually uses custom post types at all - i tried the shopp_product as one and seemed to have no effect

Comment: @Infocentre - it looks like custom post types and taxonomies were added in the new 1.2 beta.

Comment: @milo - gotcha. So is there anyway to distinguish Shopp pages from regular pages in some kind of template manor?

Comment: There are several Shopp conditional tags, for example is_shopp_page().  More can be found at https://shopplugin.net/api/category/develop/